Callback when GIF finish first loop
I need a callback when the Gif finish animating
@Composable
fun AsyncGIFLoader(
) {


    val context = LocalContext.current
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .components {
            if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                add(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
            } else {
                add(GifDecoder.Factory())
            }
        }
        .build()

    Image(
        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
            ImageRequest.Builder(context).data(data = R.drawable.mygif).apply(block = {
                size(Size.ORIGINAL)
            }).build(), imageLoader = imageLoader
        ),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
}

i tried target that displays when image loader shows onSuccess, onError but i it didn't show when Gif finish animating, it calls when the gif image loads successfully.
is there a way to detect when the Gif finish animating?

The ImageRequest.Builder has an onAnimationEnd method (when using io.coil-kt:coil-gif):
rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(data = R.drawable.mygif)
        .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
        .onAnimationEnd { /*...*/ }
        .build(),
    imageLoader = imageLoader,
)

From the docs:

Set the callback to be invoked at the end of the animation if the result is an animated Drawable.

